# Calculate Sum of values from node Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I am getting all quantity price. But I don't know how to add them all and get it under one string. Can someone pls help

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("cart").child(uid);

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("dasdasdasdad", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

            String quantityprice = (String) dataSnapshot.child("quantityprice").getValue();

            Log.d("quantityprice", String.valueOf(quantityprice));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

**In here i am getting all quantityprice value in Log
i.e:-  130,55,150**

**But i dont know how to add them all and get it under one string.
Anyhelp would be appreciated.**

**I have tried this too**

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("cart").child(uid);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("dasdasdasdad", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

                    Integer total = 0;

                    String quantityprice = (String) dataSnapshot.child("quantityprice").getValue();

                    Log.d("quantityprice", String.valueOf(quantityprice));

                    int price = Integer.valueOf(quantityprice);

                    total =+ price;
                Log.d("total",total);   }
```

but total is shown different all time.

**This is Log**

D/quantityprice: 130
D/total: 130

D/quantityprice: 55
D/total: 55

D/quantityprice: 150
D/total: 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = db.child("card").child(uid);
productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            double total = 0.00;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String quantityPrice = ds.child("quantityprice").getValue(String.class);
                total += Double.parseDouble(quantityPrice);
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "total: " + total);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
total: 335.00
```

The key to solving this problem is to parse the `String` value from the database to a `double`. Remember, if you need numbers, it's best to store them in the database as numbers and **not** as String values.